# Так же как (не могу понять правило)

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Не могу понять вот это правило на грамоте http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_710

В первом случае там представлен пример:

"**Так же как** в средневековой харчевне, нас встречали дома бревенчатые темные стены, законопаченные желтым мхом, пылающие поленья в печке и запах тмина. "

Во втором:

"Печаль полей. Совершенно **так же, как** в жмурках, бывало мы, ребята, шли с завязанными глазами, так и она переступала с лапки на лапку в направлении леса."

Почему в первом случае нет запятой, а во втором есть, хотя принцип построения у них одинаковый?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете союз "так же как", надо руководствоваться следующим правилом: сам сравнительный союз "так же как" в тексте не расчленяется: Папа Карло жил очень бедно, так же как его друг Джузеппе.(Папа Карло жил бедно и друг жил бедно) Но расчленение оказывается возможным при ином смысле, вкладываемом в предложение (в этом случае будет другой тип придаточного – образа действия): Папа Карло жил так же бедно, как жил его друг...(появляется значение одинаковой бедности: так бедно, как друг)

Так же как в средневековой харчевне, нас встречали дома бревенчатые темные стены, законопаченные желтым мхом, пылающие поленья в печке и запах тмина. "-В харчевне стены тёмные бревенчатые, и дома стены тёмные бревенчатые. - придаточное сравнительное. Если бы поставили запятую перед как, получилось бы, что встречали так, как встречали в харчевне- смысл другой.

"Печаль полей. Совершенно так же, как в жмурках, бывало мы, ребята, шли с завязанными глазами, так и она переступала с лапки на лапку в направлении леса." - она переступала лапками как? - так, как мы шли , играя  в жмурки - придат. образа действия

Comment: Спасибо большое! Теперь понял.

Comment: >Если бы поставили запятую перед как, получилось бы, что встречали так, как встречали в харчевне- смысл другой.  
  
Гм...
А ведь у Паустовского именно этот смысл.
Герои мысленно перемещаются в средневековую харчевню из романов Вальтера Скотта - а потом как бы сравнивают свои впечатления.
http://www.litra.ru/fullwork/get/woid/00484881227009095407/
Не "как будто", а именно "так же".

Comment: Когда сами отвечали, всё понимали так, теперь нет - что-то не пойму. В Вашем ответе была неточность: союз так же как относится не к харчевне, а ко всему  придаточному сравнительному, сравниваются ситуации,общий смысл не изменится, если поставить запятую, а оттенок смысла будет другой:встречали так, как встречали в харчевне, у автора этого нет, он хочет сказать, что у них дома такая  же обстановка :темно, сыро, печка, тмин. Соответственно меняются и виды придаточных.

Comment: >Когда сами отвечали, всё понимали так, теперь нет - что-то не пойму. 
  
Моя реплика относилась к Вашему объяснению, а не к моему пониманию. 
Я все понимал *не так*. Т.е. именно так, как на Грамоте. Без сомнительных (на мой взгляд) объяснений "через Папу Карлу". Вы посмотрите, в чем разница между Вашими вариантами. И папа жил бедно, и друг жил бедно. В обоих случаях. 

>В Вашем ответе была неточность   
  
Я оговорился, что объяснял "на пальцах". Что к чему относится, у меня там не в структурном смысле (как на Грамоте), а в понятийном, ибо спрашивающий Грамоту не понял.

Comment: >встречали так, как встречали в харчевне, у автора этого нет, он хочет сказать, что у них дома такая же обстановка   
  
Вы уверены? А если текст перечитать? Их в харчевне (куда их переносила сила воображения) именно что встречали стены. А потом те же (такие же) стены встречали уже дома.   
Это я все к тому, насколько зыбко объяснение, построенное на семантическом различии ситуаций. Мне структурное "грамотовское" объяснение как-то роднее. Если единый союз - то он и есть единый. Если наречие+частица+союз - то запятая. Различия в грамматической роли видны через подстановку "равно как (И)".

Comment: "Нам вспоминались средневековые харчевни - о них мы читали в романах Вальтера Скотта. На крышах этих харчевен торчали на шесте жестяные петухи или куры, заменявшие вывеску. 
     Так же как в средневековой харчевне, нас встречали дома бревенчатые темные стены, законопаченные желтым мхом, пылающие поленья в печке и запах тмина. Почему-то старый дом пропах тмином и древесной трухой". Стены их в харчевне не встречали, они только представлялись им.А вот если запятую поставить, получится, что встречали и именно так. Встречали дома так (как именно?) - как в харчевне.

Comment: "Через Папу Карлу" - классическое объяснение в методике. Только там разные предложения, а я показала на одном.И пожалуйста, отвечайте, как Вы знаете, а я - как мне представляется. Нет желания объяснять и Вам "на пальцах", в чём разница придаточного сравнительного и придаточного образа действия. Одно присоединяется союзом ТАК ЖЕ КАК, и союз относится ко всему предложению, сравнивается содержание предложений, ситуация. Второе присоединяется союзом КАК, который  относится к одному слову.Он пел так же громко, как всегда.Так же как когда-то в юности, он запел громко и твёрдо. Ученик понял, а Вы не

Comment: Людмила, спасибо,у Вас замечательное объяснение.

Answer (score 0):

Он разный. 
В первом случае "так же как" единый союз, "как" относится к харчевне.
Во втором "так же" относится к совершенно, как - ко "в жмурках".

Это я постарался объяснить на пальцах, более строгое (и более правильное) объяснение есть по Вашей ссылке.